# Grouping related postmeta data via SQL query

Tags: query, post-meta, mysql

I am using someone else's WP plugin which stores lots of related data in `wp_postmeta` using an "artificial key". So effectively we hijack `wp_postmeta` to create a nested relational database. So one row will have

```
 meta_id = 999  
 post_id = 130  
 meta_key = 'event_id'  
 meta_value = '19'
```

Then 4 other actual wp_postmeta rows that share that post_id contain the rest of the information for that virtual "row" of data. For example

```
 meta_id = 989
 post_id = 130
 meta_key = 'Name'
 meta_value = 'Fred'
```

And we will have lots of "virtual rows" (hundreds) that all share that `event_id` of 19 (and of course lots of others with different `event_id`s of their own.

I have tried many SQL queries, but I am stumped. How can I get a table that has grouped info for a common event_id? It doesn't have to have *all* the data, just one piece, such as the 'Name' field. I tried a subquery like this:

```
SELECT meta_value from wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key='name' AND 
post_id IN 
(SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key='event_id' AND meta_value='19');
```

That probably looks laughably stupid - it also doesn't work. I also tried JOIN. This seems like something that would come up a lot in WP coding, but I have searched and come up pretty much empty.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
function get_event_info($event_id = 0, $info = '' ) {
  global $wpdb;
  return $wpdb->get_col(
    $wpdb->prepare(
      "SELECT meta_value from $wpdb->postmeta WHERE 
      meta_key = '%s' AND post_id IN
      (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'event_id' AND meta_value= %s )",
      $info, $event_id
    )
  );
}
```

Use this like so:

```
$names = get_event_info( 19 , 'Name' );
if ( ! empty($names) ) {
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo '<li>' . $name . '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

Please be sure the second parameter is exactly the same as the `meta_key`: in your example `meta_key = 'Name'` but the SQL query is `WHERE meta_key='name'`, case is different!

Answer (score 0):

You can select your posts by using the meta_query parameter in the [WP_Query class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Get all the post ID's of the posts who have a shared event_id of 19.

You can use the ID's later on to get all necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled in the same problem and get more or less what I wanted in this way:

```
SELECT t.post_id, t.meta_value, u.meta_value
FROM  `wp_postmeta` t INNER JOIN  `wp_postmeta` u
ON t.post_id = u.post_id
WHERE
u.meta_key =  'first_key' AND
t.meta_key =  'second_key'
```